# Moving a Checked Li to the Bottom of a UL

Tags: javascript

I am making a todo list, i have just about everything for it figured out but one area i am stuck on is my UL and Li.
Basically when you enter items into the list, you have the ability to click the checkbox beside said item when you complete the task, and it will put a line through the text.
But i also want it to move that item to the bottom of the list when it is clicked.
would anyone be able to help me with how i would go about doing that

code Below

```
// making event listener for adding item
let addBTN = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBTN.addEventListener('click', addItem);

// this creates a new li based on the entered value in the text box that it gets when you hit the button
// Through Research found that setAttribute isn't really needed and i can just use .id , .type etc
function addItem() {
  // Creating needed elements as well as getting text from textbox
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  let myLiValue = document.getElementById('textBoxAdd').value;
  let liTextNode = document.createElement("label");
  liTextNode.textContent = myLiValue;

  // makes div for li
  let newDivID = ('div_' + myLiValue);
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.id = newDivID;

  // makes checkboxes for the li 
  let newCheckBoxID = ('checkbox_' + myLiValue);
  let newCheckBox = document.createElement('input');
  newCheckBox.type = 'checkbox';
  newCheckBox.id = newCheckBoxID;


  // makes delete button for the li
  let newDeleteID = ('deleteButton_' + myLiValue);
  let newDeleteButton = document.createElement("button")
  newDeleteButton.type = 'button';
  newDeleteButton.id = newDeleteID
  newDeleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
  //newDeleteButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteItem()');
  newDeleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';

  // appends it to my newDiv
  newDiv.appendChild(newCheckBox);
  newDiv.appendChild(liTextNode);
  newDiv.appendChild(newDeleteButton);
  // then appends my new div to the new Li
  newLi.appendChild(newDiv);

  // this just makes sure a user cant enter in a blank value
  if (myLiValue == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Something Before Hitting Add Item");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('theNewList').appendChild(newLi);
    document.getElementById('textBoxAdd').value = "";
  }
}


//creating event listener for checkbox line through text and moving item
let theList = document.getElementById('theNewList');
theList.addEventListener('click', checkedComplete);

// function that will target every check box in the list and if any get checked then it will add a line through the text
function checkedComplete(event) {
  const checkboxElement = event.target;
  if (checkboxElement.type === 'checkbox') {
    if (checkboxElement.checked) {
      checkboxElement.nextElementSibling.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';

      // add in moving item
  
    } else {
      checkboxElement.nextElementSibling.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    }
  }
}

// adds deleteItem listener to the list
theList.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);

function deleteItem(event) {
  const deleteButton = event.target;
  if (deleteButton.type === 'button') {
    const deleteParentNode = deleteButton.parentNode;
    deleteParentNode.parentNode.removeChild(deleteParentNode);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the following logic where you have *// add in moving item* comment:

```
const theList = document.getElementById('theNewList');
const lastListItem = theList.children[theList.children.length - 1];
theList.insertBefore(lastListItem, checkboxElement.parentNode.parentNode);
```

We're selecting your `ul` and searching for its last `li` and then we're simply placing the `li` belonging to the `checkboxElement` after the last `li`.

**Working example:**

```js
// making event listener for adding item
let addBTN = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBTN.addEventListener('click', addItem);

// this creates a new li based on the entered value in the text box that it gets when you hit the button
// Through Research found that setAttribute isn't really needed and i can just use .id , .type etc
function addItem() {
  // Creating needed elements as well as getting text from textbox
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  let myLiValue = document.getElementById('textBoxAdd').value;
  let liTextNode = document.createElement("label");
  liTextNode.textContent = myLiValue;

  // makes div for li
  let newDivID = ('div_' + myLiValue);
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.id = newDivID;

  // makes checkboxes for the li 
  let newCheckBoxID = ('checkbox_' + myLiValue);
  let newCheckBox = document.createElement('input');
  newCheckBox.type = 'checkbox';
  newCheckBox.id = newCheckBoxID;


  // makes delete button for the li
  let newDeleteID = ('deleteButton_' + myLiValue);
  let newDeleteButton = document.createElement("button")
  newDeleteButton.type = 'button';
  newDeleteButton.id = newDeleteID
  newDeleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
  //newDeleteButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteItem()');
  newDeleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';

  // appends it to my newDiv
  newDiv.appendChild(newCheckBox);
  newDiv.appendChild(liTextNode);
  newDiv.appendChild(newDeleteButton);
  // then appends my new div to the new Li
  newLi.appendChild(newDiv);

  // this just makes sure a user cant enter in a blank value
  if (myLiValue == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Something Before Hitting Add Item");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('theNewList').appendChild(newLi);
    document.getElementById('textBoxAdd').value = "";
  }
}


//creating event listener for checkbox line through text and moving item
let theList = document.getElementById('theNewList');
theList.addEventListener('click', checkedComplete);

// function that will target every check box in the list and if any get checked then it will add a line through the text
function checkedComplete(event) {
  const checkboxElement = event.target;
  if (checkboxElement.type === 'checkbox') {
    if (checkboxElement.checked) {
      checkboxElement.nextElementSibling.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';

      const theList = document.getElementById('theNewList');
      const lastListItem = theList.children[theList.children.length - 1];
      theList.insertBefore(checkboxElement.parentNode.parentNode, lastListItem.nextSilbing);
  
    } else {
      checkboxElement.nextElementSibling.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    }
  }
}

// adds deleteItem listener to the list
theList.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);

function deleteItem(event) {
  const deleteButton = event.target;
  if (deleteButton.type === 'button') {
    const deleteParentNode = deleteButton.parentNode;
    deleteParentNode.parentNode.removeChild(deleteParentNode);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="textBoxAdd" type="text" />
<button id="addBtn" type="button">Add</button>
<ul id="theNewList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a storage of you todos, right? Even if you did not think about it, it can do all the work. Just create the array (you could use localStorage to prevent you data from disappearing after browser is restarted) containing your todos and their condition, like

```
const todos = [{todo:"watch the movie", completed: false}, {...}, {...}]
```

Now you can easily add or remove items with standard array methods pop&push, delete with splice, filter etc. After array is mdified, just update the page and build your list using Array.map.